# Loading JQuery data tables using ajax response at regular intervals

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to load Jquery datatables using Ajax response every 30 seconds. My Model object format is

```
MyObject{
 List<Employee> data1;
 List<Employee> data2;
 List<Employee> data3;
 List<Employee> data4;
.....
}
Employee{
  String name;
  int age;
  LocalDate doj;
  String dept;
...
}
```

I am loading this data on document ready like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 initialzeTables();
        setInterval(function () {
            initialzeTables();
        }, 30000);

function initialzeTables() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "jsonsource.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (d) {
                    d.date = $.fn.getCurrentDate()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    handleResponse(result);
                }
            });
        }

}
function handleResponse(result) {
            table1Id = $("#table1");
            table1.clear();
            displayData(result.data1,table1Id);
            table1.draw();
        }

        function displayData(data, table){
            for(var i in data){
                var rowData =data[i];
                var rowStr = "<tr>"
                    + "<td>"+rowData.Name+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+rowData.age+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+rowData.doj+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+rowData.dept+"</td>"
                    + "</tr>"
               $("#"+table+" tbody").append(rowStr);
            }
        }
```

I have made changes for 1st table only,but looks like it is not working, UI is shows "No data available". Surely some thing is wrong, Can't figure it out. Any one to the rescue ?

Comment: what do you do with result.data2 , result.data3, etc ?? how do you account for that?

Comment: Why don't you use the `"ajax"` attribute of `DataTable` and then use the `.ajax.reload()` method from the DataTable's API to reload the table's data every 30 seconds? See this link: [https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)

Comment: What's the point of `$.fn.getCurrentDate()`? Or, phrased differently, you downloaded a jQuery extension that gives you the current date...? Is that useful? Also, if the purpose of this is to prevent the browser from caching the Ajax response, that can be done differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for replying. I figured it out from [this](http://prabhakarsinghblogs.blogspot.in/2013/12/to-populate-jquery-datatable-by-passing.html)

```
        <div class="filter">
            Search Data: <input type="text" id="filtertext" placeholder="Filter...">
        </div>
        <h3><font color='red'>Table1 Data</font></h3>
        <table id="table1" style="background-color: #edf1fa"
               class="display compact cell-border">

        </table>
        <br>
        <h3><font color='green'>Table2 Data</font></h3>
        <table id="table2" style="background-color: #edf1fa"
               class="display compact cell-border">

        </table>
        <br>
        <h3><font color='salmon'>Table3 Data</font></h3>
        <table id="table3" style="background-color: #edf1fa"
               class="display compact cell-border">

        </table>
        <br>
        <h3><font color='violet'>Table4 Data</font></h3>
        <table id="table4" style="background-color: #edf1fa"
               class="display compact cell-border">
        </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        buildHeader();
        var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable({
            "sDom": 'rt',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ordering": false,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        });
        var table2 = $('#table2').DataTable({
            "sDom": 'rt',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ordering": false,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        });
        var table3 = $('#table3').DataTable({
            "sDom": 'rt',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ordering": false,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        });
        var table4 = $('#table4').DataTable({
            "sDom": 'rt',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ordering": false,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        });

        $("#filtertext").on('keyup', function (e) {
            table.search(this.value).draw();
        });
        initialzeTables();
        setInterval(function () {
            initialzeTables();
        }, 30000);
        function buildHeader() {
            var rowStr = "<thead>"
                    + "<tr>"
                    + "<th>name</th>"
                    + "<th>Age</th>"
                    + "<th>DOJ</th>"
                    + "<th>Dept</th>"
                    + "</tr>"
                    + "</thead>";
            $("table.display ").append(rowStr);
        }

        function initialzeTables() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "jsonsource.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                data:  {
                    "date" : getCurrentDate()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    handleResponse(result);
                }
            });
        }

        function handleResponse(result) {
            table1Id = $("#table1");
            table2Id = $("#table2");
            table3Id = $("#table3");
            table4Id = $("#table4");

            table1.destroy();
            table2.destroy();
            table3.destroy();
            table4.destroy();

            table1 = displayData(result.data1, table1Id, table1);
            table2 =  displayData(result.data2, table2Id, table2);
            table3 = displayData(result.data3, table3Id, table3);
            table4 = displayData(result.data4, table4Id, table4);
        }

        function displayData(data, tableSelector, datatable) {
            datatable = tableSelector.DataTable({
                "sDom": 'rt',
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ordering": false,
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "data": data,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "age"},
                    {"data": "doj"},
                    {"data": "dept"},
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        'targets': [0],
                        'orderable': false,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            data = data != null ? data : ' ';
                            return '<a href="/URL?name=' + data +'">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                    },
                 ]
            });
            return datatable;
        }

        function getCurrentDate() {
            return $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());
        }
    });
</script>
```